# I get a 404 error when he should not :laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I developed an API and I have a problem with this page I add it in my route and always I get a **404 error** I don't know why

this my controller:

```
class InsertPPictureController extends Controller
{
    public function profilepicture (Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $validator =    Validator::make($input, [
            'id_user'=> 'required',
            'picture'=> 'image|nullable|max:1999'
        ] );

        $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
        $user_id = $request->id ;

        if($request->hasFile('picture')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $user_id.'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('picture')->storeAs('public/profilepic', $fileNameToStore);
            $user->pic_path = $fileNameToStore ;
            $user->update();


        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage';
        }

        return response()->json(' Success : User updated with success ',200);
    }
}
```

and this is my api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.verify']], function() {
    Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('postcreditscards', 'CreditsCardsController@stockcards');
    Route::get('getcreditscards', 'CreditsCardsController@index');
    Route::get('getmybalance', 'MyBalanceController@index');
    Route::get('getuserdata', 'AuthController@getuser');
    Route::post('sendMoneyTransaction', 'MyBalanceController@updatebalance');
    Route::post('isvalidnumber', 'AuthController@validnumber');
   Route::post('updateuser', 'AuthController@updateuser');
     Route::post('insertprofilepicture','InsertPPictureController@profilepicture');

});
```

all the pages work fine only this page doesn't work

```
Route::post('insertprofilepicture','InsertPPictureController@profilepicture');
```

Comment: insertprofilepicture is an post request it will not open via browser you will be needing tool like postman to test it

Comment: @Rohit Dalal the error would be "Method not allowed", not 404, in the case you mentioned

Comment: Dude, Laravel has added new pages for errors such as 404, 419 etc in errors folder of views. Please check them and you are using 5.6 it should be there. 404 is route not found and its same as Method not allowed only laravel has changed how to handle the error.

Comment: yes i use postman

Comment: @RohitDalal "dude", you must be kidding :)  when you try to access a route using wrong method but route DOES exist, you get "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" and when you try to access a route which DOES NOT exist, you get 404 "page not found" exception. It is pretty standard in all versions of Laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting 404 error because of the following line in you controller code:

`$user = User::findOrFail($request->id);`

The `id` you are providing, does not exist in your users table and as you are not catching the exception hence Laravel is returning a 404 response, which is actually `ModelNotFoundException`

Reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)

Go to : "Not Found Exceptions" section of the above link. Here is some lines from doc:

`If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($user,1);die();
```

just put in this line after the
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->id); 
line.  i suggest you to check the data array pass to this controller. if it is pass, after line by line you can check.

Comment: you can use `dd($user);` instead